# Encoding characters HTML in python

Tags: python, html

I have a problem with one of my python program :

"é" doesn't display well on the website they show like this � even thought I encoded in UTF-8.
I don't know why this is happening. Help would be appreciated ! :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sqlite3

print("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8")


# Ecriture d'une page Web avec un formulaire
print('''
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Ajout Région</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 style='text-align:center'>Ajouter une région</h1>

        <form method='get' action='insertionRegion.py'>
            Nom de la région : <input type='text' name='nomReg'/><br/>''')

print('''
            <br/>
            <input type='submit' value='Ajouter'/>
        </form>


        <hr/>
        <a href='index.py'>Retour au menu</a>

    </body>
</html>''')
```

PS : Sorry for my english.

Comment: You probably have set your editor to the wrong encoding.

Comment: Remove `print("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8")` and  try using `<meta charset="iso-8859-1">`

Comment: I have no issue when using "é". You shouldn't need to add anything to the `.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just found the problem it was because of the python heading

```
print("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8")
```

I just removed this charset.
And also I changed  `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to  `<meta charset="iso-8859-1">`
Thank you for your answers it helped me to discover the problem !
Have a good day !